# Core-Data doesn't save in an asynchronous call

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to use Core Data to save data from a Google Firebase call. When I save the managed context it saves but when I exit the app and reopen it all the data is gone.

```
ref.child(exhibit).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    for item in snapshot.children {
        let animalObject = animal(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
        let managedContext = self.appDelegate!.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let animalEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Animal", into: managedContext)
        animalEntity.setValue(animalObject.name, forKeyPath: "name")
        animalEntity.setValue(animalObject.information!, forKeyPath: "information")
        animalEntity.setValue(animalObject.imageReference!, forKeyPath: "imageURL")
        self.animals!.append(animalObject)

        do {
            try managedContext.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Couldn not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
})
```

I know the snapshot correctly gets the data. Also I have tried setValue with `forKey` as the parameter name instead of `forKeyPath`.

Comment: Did you check your entity name in core data that set a value ?

Comment: Show the code for appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext. How is this context set up?

Comment: Yes the entity name is correct. And how would I show that code? I know this works because if I do a managedContext fetch request on Animal in the do block it will return the recently saved context, but when I exit the app and restart it is no longer there.

Comment: self.animals is an array? What exactly does append do? And what is the purpose of  self.animals?

Answer (score 0):

The key is in the word "asynchronous". You're using the managedObjectContext from the appDelegate, which is probably running on the main queue, in a secondary thread. You have several options:

- collect the data from snapshot and then call, on the main thread, a method that saves to the appDelegate's managedObjectContext. The same can be achieved by posting notifications.
- create a new managedObjectContext of type privateQueueConcurrencyType (init(concurrencyType:) and save the snapshot data inside a block (performBlockAndWait()). Details can be found on [NSManagedObjectContext reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext)

Objective-C example which assumes that self.persistentContainer has been set and the data is available in an NSArray of dictionaries: `

```
- (void)saveData
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *_privateContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    _privateContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator;

    __block __typeof__(self) blockSelf = self;
    [_privateContext performBlock:^(void) {
        NSError *error = nil;

        for (NSDictionary *animalDict in blockSelf.dataArray) {
            Animal *anAnimal = [Books managedObjectWithEntity:@"Animal" managedObjectContext:_privateContext];
            anAnimal.name = [animalDict valueForKey:@"name"];
            anAnimal.fluffiness = [animalDict valueForKey:@"fluffiness"];
        }

        if ([_privateContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"%@ %@ Data was added and saved", [blockSelf class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
        } else if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@", [blockSelf class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd),
                  error.description); //type macerror <errornumber> in Terminal for more info
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@ %@ Data was added but not saved", [blockSelf class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
        }
    }];
}
```